# execute command within command

Tags: ubuntu, solaris, linux

i want to ask if i can execute command within command ?
like :-  command (other command)

Comment: Do you want the output of (other command) to be passed to command or are you trying to achieve something else ?

Comment: yes exactly i want to use the output of command to passed it to other command

Comment: Then [pipes](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec16.html) are what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sounds like you want "piping"

as in:
`ls -1 | grep "txt"`

Comment: Piping is definitely the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

$() can be used and for bash are preferred over backticks, but are not portable.